# my discord python bot isn't writing to file

Tags: python, discord, bots

I'm trying to write a discord bot, that when you type !create, you can type in the scores of every person and it should save the scores to a text file, but it keeps wiping the text file and I don't know why this is happening.

My Code:

```
import discord

client = discord.Client()
channel = client.get_channel("channelid")

file = open("TournamentScores.txt", "a")

tournament = False
scoreset1 = False
scoreset2 = False


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("~Bot Started~")
    channel = client.get_channel("channelid")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    print("received message") 
    channel = client.get_channel("channelid")
    
    global tournament, scoreset1, scoreset2

    if message.content.startswith("!create") and not tournament:
        print("Tournament Created")
        tournament = True
        await message.channel.send("Goals for Conner:")
        file.write("~Tournament~ \n")

    
    elif message.content.isdigit():
        if tournament and not scoreset1:
            scoreset1 = True
            ConnerTemplate = "Conner - " + message.content
            file.writelines(ConnerTemplate + " \n")
            await message.channel.send("Goals for Ewan:")

        elif scoreset1 and not scoreset2:
            scoreset2 = True
            EwanTemplate = "Ewan - " + message.content
            file.writelines(EwanTemplate + " \n")
            await message.channel.send("Goals for Jack:")
        
        elif scoreset2 == True and tournament == True:
            JackTemplate = "Jack - " + message.content
            file.writelines(JackTemplate + " \n")
            await message.channel.send("Goals for Thomas:")

            tournament = False
            
        elif not tournament and file == open:
            ThomasTemplate = "Thomas - " + message.content
            file.writelines(ThomasTemplate + " \n")          

            file.close()

            tournament = False
```

Comment: Are you certain that the txt file is actually being wiped? You are opening the file in `"a"` append mode, so this shouldn't be possible. Could you try writing something in the txt file, then running your program to see if it deletes it?

Comment: Ok, well before instead of "a", I wrote "w", and it was wiping it, it doesn't wipe the file but it doesn't write to it @Gbox4